# Including Google Sitemap Api in PHP with OAuth2.0

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api

While integrating Google Sitemap API in PHP I am logged in with Google OAuth2.0 (works like charm), but this code does not fit :

```
$key = 'SOME-GOOGLE-KEY';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites?key=$key"), true);

print_r($obj);
```

Error-message:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

The API-key is correct and has no restrictions. It's bound to "Google Search Console API". The "Google Search Console API" is activated also.

How to authorize correctly?

Answer (score 0):

At least i found a solution called: google-api-php-client which is hosted at GitHub:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client